# Scraping all images from a wikipedia page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all images from wikipedia page :

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

webpage = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks')
bs = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
print(bs)
aList= bs.find_all('a',{'class':'image'})
for a in aList:
    if(a['href']=="*ICBC*"):
        print(a['href'])
```

Can you please help with a code to
1 print all href of images of ICBC bank
2 getting images directly to a word document

Comment: In which line are you getting error? Which programming language are you using (you need to tag it)?

Comment: I am getting error for line 6